# How to Restore Registry from bootable usb in Windows 10 (unable to boot to safe mode)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

I mistakenly deleted important registry entries in Windows 10 Enterprise v20H1 and now Windows won't boot, not even in safe mode, and am only able to boot to the Recovery Environment. I have the bootable USB I used to install the OS, but no restore points or recovery media.

- I have already tried `sfc /scannow /bootdir...` and `dism` command (which gives error `0x800f0801`)

Can I restore registry files with the original registry keys from the bootable USB, and if so, how?

Comment: The recommended way to fix would be to perform a Repair Install by launching `setup.exe` while booted to Windows, choosing to keep all files. While you can try exporting the registry hives from a `\sources\install.wim`||`\sources\install.esd` _(located within `\Windows\System32\config`)_, it's unlikely to fix the issue and if it does, you're likely going to have more problems that arise because the Registry isn't static and is modified by every program installed to the OS. `DISM` and `SFC` won't fix the issue because the Registry hives aren't static and have no backup in `%WinDir%\WinSxS`.

Comment: You could in theory import the hive in question, and make changes that way, but you would have to somehow export the keys you need into that hive instead of the one that was running.  You should be able to figure out the syntax by exporting a single key to a file from that mounted hive.  This would literally put the keys back, it probably will NOT, solve the problem.  Since you didn’t provide us any information on what keys you deleted I cannot do research

Comment: @JW0914 I can't boot to windows, registry files that got deleted were essential to boot the OS. I already mentioned this in the description.

Comment: @Moab There is no restore point, as I have mentioned in the description.

Comment: @Ramhound Can you please tell how can I get the hives to import, I know how to import but don't know from where to get the lost registries.

Comment: I accidently deleted several registries from "Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft", which are not in use when pc is booted, but are used while booting.

Comment: _(I re-arranged the content in my first comment after writing it - the importing of the `install.wim`||`.esd` hives would likely allow you to boot if hives other than the `HKCU` hive were modified, at which point a Repair Install could be done)_

Comment: If only `HKCU` keys were deleted, enable the default Admin account in WinRE, reboot to Windows, create a replacement user for your user, log in under that user, copy non-hidden folders to your new user's `%UserProfile%` from your old one, copy the old user's `AppData` folder and `.dat` files [user registry hive] to a directory other than the new user's `%UserProfile%`, then delete the old user and create a Restore Point. Export the new user's `HKCU` hive, mount the old user's `.dat` hive and export it, then import it into the new user's `HKCU` hive and reboot.

Comment: While there is a hive for the HKCU you are better off, enabling the built-in Administrator, and fixing the problem within Windows rather than entirely in WinRE.  The location of the hive file for the current user is well documented.

Comment: @JW0914 and Ramhound Thanks for the help. I extracted \sources\install.wim/Windows\System32\config and copy pasted the files using command  prompt. The system booted with several errors popping on start, as expected. Then did the repair install by running setup.exe from the bootable usb.

Comment: @TontyTon Copy/paste is not export/import - copy/paste replaces the hives, whereas exporting the default hives and importing into the current hives only replaces the default keys and not the keys that have been added to the system since Windows was installed, as hives are not static _(export/import is done via [`Reg`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg) or the GUI `RegEdit`)_. Due to the copy/paste, you're likely going to have inconveniences with installed applications and settings for both applications and the OS, possibly w/ drivers as well.

Comment: @JW0914 I think restoring won't have worked from recovery environment. But now I solved the issue, so can't try.

Comment: @TontyTon I'm unsure what you're referring to, as I never suggested restoring anything from WinRE. WinRE can fix most system issues, as that's the entire purpose of WinRE [**Win**dows **R**ecovery **E**nvironment]